# Print the address of a variable in memory

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
main() {
    int i=9;

    printf("\nAddress of i = %d", &i);
    printf("\nAddress of i = %x", &i);
    printf("\nAddress of i = %u", &i);
    printf("\nAddress of i = %p", &i);
    printf("\nValue of i = %d",i);
}
```

When I use `%p` I get: Value of `i` = `0xbfd08d5c`
Other formats `%d`,`%x`,`%u` don't work.

Comment: That *seems* like a valid address in memory to me. What are you expecting to see?

Comment: @WaiHaLee Something like this > Address of i = 65524
Value of i = 3

Comment: I am trying this exercise: main( )
{
int i = 3 ;
printf ( "\nAddress of i = %u", &i ) ;
printf ( "\nValue of i = %d", i ) ;
printf ( "\nValue of i = %d", *( &i ) ) ;
}
The output of the above program would be:
Address of i = 65524
Value of i = 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you are not allowed to use `%d`, `%x`, or `%u` for an address. You should use only `%p` - that is the only valid format to use for pointers.

Moreover, since `%p` expects a void pointer, you need to add a cast to `&i` operation:

```
printf("\nAddress of i = %p", (void*)&i);
```

Although the code would work without a cast on most platforms, it is a good idea to add a cast to guarantee compatibility with platforms where a pointer to an `int` and a void pointer have different representations. I am not sure if there are any such platforms, but the standard does not prohibit them.

Comment: I understand that other formatters are not allowed except %p, but what if I just want to print the location address in integer as shown in the above link. Now, how does it print address in int: look @ link above.

Comment: @sunnyp. , That article is wrong. `%d` expects an `int` but `&var` is of type `int*`. If you look at the C11 standard , 7.21.6.1 , 9)"If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.  **If any argument is
not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
undefined.**". So, if you use `%d` for printing the address, your code exhibits Undefined Behavior. Basically, that's wrong. Anything can happen if you try it.

Comment: I wonder if casting the pointer as `(unsigned int)` has defined behaviour. If so, the OP can do what he wants without involving UB.

Answer (score -1):

address is a positive integer, therefore, using "%u" , i.e., unsigned int, can print the correct address value.

p.s., "%p" in hexadecimal format and "%u" in common decimal format.

Comment: On most 64bit systems the result would be wrong if printing an address as `unsigned int`.

Comment: unsigned can be used to both int and long.

Comment: `%u` is for `unsigned int` only. To print an `unsigned long int` the length modifier `l` has to be used, giving `%lu`.